# How to randomize different numbers for subgroup of rows pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe. I need to randomize values taken from list for all rows within given condition. I did:

```
df = df.withColumn('rand_col', f.when(f.col('condition_col') == condition, random.choice(my_list)))
```

but the effect is, that it randomizes only one value and assigns it to all rows:

[image]

How can I randomize separately for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- use `rand` and `floor` from `pyspark.sql.functions` to create a random indexing column to index into your `my_list`
- create a column in which the `my_list` value is repeated
- index into that column using `f.col`

It would look something like this:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

my_list = [1, 2, 30]
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 0),
        (2, 1),
        (3, 1),
        (4, 0),
        (5, 1),
        (6, 1),
        (7, 0),
    ],
    ["id", "condition"]
)

df = df.withColumn('rand_index', f.when(f.col('condition') == 1, f.floor(f.rand() * len(my_list))))\
       .withColumn('my_list', f.array([f.lit(x) for x in my_list]))\
       .withColumn('rand_value', f.when(f.col('condition') == 1, f.col("my_list")[f.col("rand_index")]))

df.show()
+---+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| id|condition|rand_index|   my_list|rand_value|
+---+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|        0|      null|[1, 2, 30]|      null|
|  2|        1|         0|[1, 2, 30]|         1|
|  3|        1|         2|[1, 2, 30]|        30|
|  4|        0|      null|[1, 2, 30]|      null|
|  5|        1|         1|[1, 2, 30]|         2|
|  6|        1|         2|[1, 2, 30]|        30|
|  7|        0|      null|[1, 2, 30]|      null|
+---+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Okay, I can make it into f.floor(f.rand() * len(my_list) - thats a nice step ahead, but now, how to insert into spark dataframe a value from the list using the index we randomized? Naive my_list[f.floor(f.rand() * len(my_list)] returns {TypeError}list indices must be integers or slices, not Column

Comment: Hey @Manaslu, I had misread your question a bit. Sorry for that! I've edited my answer, does that look more like what you're looking for?

Comment: @Koedlt Realised you updated your answer, I've removed mine.

Comment: @Koedlt works! Accepted, the answer.